# Unable to edit file in WSL from Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have created `~/fastai/Dockerfile` inside Ubuntu running in WSL. I tried to open it in windows notepad. First opened the folder in explorer:

```
~$ cd fastai/
~/fastai$ explorer.exe .
```

Then opened Dockerfile in notepad. Edited and tried to save. But it does not allow to save, instead shows Save As dialog. I tried to edit and save it in Notepad++. It gives following error:

[image]

However, if I create a new file from Windows in WSL folder and try to edit and save it. It works. So earlier files created in same way, before Windows restart are rendered un-editable.

What I am missing?

PS: I am running Windows 10 build 19045.3086 version 22H2

Comment: Why are you not viewing the files within File Explorer by navigating to \\wsl.localhost\\

Comment: I was opened `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\fastai` in Windows and tried to open `Dockerfile` in notepad. It was not allowed to edit and save.

Comment: \\wsl$\\ hasn’t been the correct path to for over a year. **Try the path I suggested**